# Trying to upload multiple images but it is uploading only one

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple images. I am using Codeigniter and I know there is a built in file upload class but I am just experimenting with my custom made image upload library. I have provided the code below.

The problem I am facing with the following code is it is just uploading only one (the one that is selected at last in the form) image.

Could you please kindly tell me where I am doing wrong?

My Controller:

```
function img_upload(){

   $this->load->library('image_upload');         

    $image1= $this->image_upload->upload_image('imagefile1');
    $image2= $this->image_upload->upload_image('imagefile2');
    $image3= $this->image_upload->upload_image('imagefile3');

   echo $image1 ."<br>"; echo $image2;  
}
```

application/libraries/image_upload.php (Custom made library)

```
  function upload_image($image_info){

    $image=$_FILES[$image_info]['name'];
    $filename = stripslashes($image);
    $extension = $this->getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

    $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;

   $newname="support/images/products/".$image_name;
   $uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_info]['tmp_name'], $newname);

   if($uploaded) {return $image_name; } else {return FALSE;}
}
```

My Form

```
 <form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
 action="<?php echo base_url();?>add/img_upload" method="post" name="myForm">

  <input type="file" name="imagefile1" size="20" /><br>
  <input type="file" name="imagefile2" size="20" /><br>
  <input type="file" name="imagefile3" size="20" /><br>
   <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="upload" />    
 </form>
```

Comment: have you tried printing the generated file names to see if it is overwriting the image each time?

Comment: Yes I have tried and it is displaying the same file name twice. thanks

Comment: What about small files? I had a similar problem once because the files I was uploading where to big for the maximum limit.

Comment: @bottleboot. For both small and large files the result is the same. thanks

Comment: What is the name of that one image that gets uploaded? imagefile1, 2 or 3?

Comment: may be your library is not available for the second function call.

Comment: @bottleboot If I upload three images then imagefile3 gets uploaded. if I upload two images then imagefile2.. you get the idea :)

Comment: @Manoj But how come it is uploading the last selected image then.? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create some kind of rollback functionality and use CI native lib . it's little extra work for the server but it's less/clean/easyTOdebug code and it works .

```
function do_upload()
{
```

1 - configuration

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    // other configurations 

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $error = array('stat'=>0 , 'reason'=>'' ;
```

2- uploading

```
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_1'))
        {
            $error['stat'] = 1 ;
            $error['reason'] = $this->upload->display_errors() ;

        }
        else
        { $uploaded_array[] = $uploaded_file_name ; } 

            // you may need to clean and re initialize library before new upload 
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_2'))
        {
            $error['stat'] = 1 ;
            $error['reason'] = $this->upload->display_errors() ;

        }
        else
        { $uploaded_array[] = $uploaded_file_name ; }
```

3 - checking for errors and rollback at the end

```
if($error['stat'] == 1 )
{   
    $upload_path = './upload/';
    if(!empty($uploaded_array))
    {
        foreach( $uploaded_array as $uploaded )
        { 
           $file = $upload_path.$uploaded;
           if(is_file($file))
           unlink($file);
        }
    }
    echo 'there was a problem : '.$error['reason'];
}
else
{
   echo 'success';
}




}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using Codeigniter's naive library because with it I cannot check if all images that are selected for upload is valid (I mean size and format) before uploading any image. I mean If there is a validation problem with any of my images then I certainly don't want to upload any images. But in codeigniter  if there is any validation error with any image, without that particular image the rest of the images get uploaded, which I don't want.

Comment: And another problem is that the image upload feature in my form is optional, so if I select two images instead of three codeigniters shows and error saying that I didn't select a file to upload but in the background it already uploaded those two files.

Comment: from what i see you check the images in the library and you check and upload each image separately . that means even if one image has a problem it still uploads other pics .

Comment: Yes, I haven't worked on that yet, I will write code for that after making sure that all images are getting uploaded. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your code but it is uploading  image even though there was a validation error in one of the two images. And it is showing error messages :`Message: Undefined variable: uploaded_file_name` and `Message: unlink() [function.unlink]: Invalid argument`.

Comment: sorry you have to use unlink with relative path to the file check out the `$upload_path` declaration in third part of codes and put your upload directory in it . also i forgot to check if the `uploaded_array` is not empty

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem, and thought it could help someone if I share.

The problem was in the image_upload.php file (custom made library), specifically in this line:

```
 $image_name=time().'.'.$extension; //
```

time() was perhaps overwriting the files. So I replaced my previous code with the following:

```
function upload_image($image_info){

     $image=$_FILES[$image_info]['name'];
     $filename = stripslashes($image);
     $extension = $this->getExtension($filename);
     $extension = strtolower($extension);

     $image_name=$this->get_random_number().'.'.$extension;

     $newname="support/images/products/".$image_name;
     $uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$image_info]['tmp_name'], $newname);

  if($uploaded) {return $image_name; } else {return FALSE;}
 }


  function get_random_number(){

    $today = date('YmdHi');
    $startDate = date('YmdHi', strtotime('-10 days'));
    $range = $today - $startDate;
    $rand1 = rand(0, $range);
    $rand2 = rand(0, 600000);
    return  $value=($rand1+$rand2);
}
```

Comment: you know php already has native uniqid() function to generate Unique string using time and date .

Comment: By this time, I have developed another function to check the validation error before uploading images. If there is error in any of the uploaded images it won't upload rest of the images. It is now working perfectly :) Thanks for your time.